# Mobile application authentication & session management from java application

Tags: java, authentication, mobile-application, session-management

I'm looking for suggestions for below listed problem

I have a web application which is developed on java & current web application developed with below features

1. Authentication (Login/Logout)
2. Session management
3. Dashboard with subscription and profile edit
4. Some CRUD Functionality.

Now, i'm planning for mobile app with same futures. Since my current application can able to provide RESTFul Service to do CRUD operations. Let me know best approach to achieve authentication & session management in mobile app?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Have a good day.

Comment: have you searched anything from your side. Please show some research efforts.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I'm gone to Xauth, Oauth, RESTFul Service and SAML Approach.. But not got clarity still & I'm trying to learn some more possibilities. Now I'm looking for best practices & casestudies.. thanks for commenting.

Comment: @OpenSorceDev Mention this in your code. Now its ok.

Comment: Can someone help me out here?

Comment: which platform are you using.

Comment: Java @ Server Side & Objective C @ iOS, Java @ Andriod

Comment: Hope Stackoverflow folks are busy with reputations. thanks for not answering m question. let me close the same.

Comment: Hey @OpenSourceDev were you able to figure it out eventually? If yes, would be great if you can share the same. I am doing exact same stuff here.

Comment: Dear Shailesh,

I'm done lot of research & developed 2 POC's

Those are

Experiment 1: OAUTH2.0 with Apache Oltu

Experiment 2: SSO with SAML

As per my requirement, Experiment 1 is best approach.